# Some Content Overlapping Sidebar

Tags: html, css, tumblr

so I'm new to CSS and HTML. I'm in the process of modifying a basic code for my blog on Tumblr, and I noticed that only two posts don't overlap my sidebar. I don't know what's wrong or how to fix it. Please help.

Here's my blog, so you can see what I mean: [X](http://witcchbitch.tumblr.com)
Here's my code, in case that helps: [X](http://pastebin.com/304hjHLQ)

Thank you.

Comment: Can you describe your Q a little more. I checked yoru blog but didn't undertood your issue

Comment: When I go to my blog and scroll down, only a few posts look "normal", the rest after that overlap the sidebar.

Comment: You have `</div>` in the loop of the posts. you may want to wrap the post to the `<div id="content">`

Comment: THANK YOU. @MichaelPon, thank you so much. I'm so new to this and have been trying to figure it out for hours, I felt like crying I was so frustrated. This fixed my issue, so thank you so so much!

Comment: You're welcome @Bekah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an iframe inserted at the middle of the contents. please remove that, and the layout fixes.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the margin for the #posts

```
div#posts {
    margin: 60px 0 60px 450px;
    padding: 20px 0;
}
```